# Find world-space image-plane coordinates

Tags: camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have a fully calibrated camera looking straight onto the world origin.

I'm trying to figure out a piece of algorithm that doesn't make any sense to me.

The objective is to find the corners of the image plane in the world coordinate system.

Assume I have the left-upper corner of the image plane, p.
I get it's camera space coordinates by left multiplying by the inverse of the calibration matrix, denote it by x.

Then the algorithm proceeds as follows:

Finds t, where t is third column of (K^-1 * P), where K is the calibration matrix, and P is the projection matrix. If I understand correctly, this gives me the world center in the camera space.

Then, this is the part I don't understand.
The *world space* position of the point we're after is defined as:

||t|| * x / ||x||

It doesn't make any intuitive sense to multiply the normalized vector originating from the camera center by the distance of the camera to the origin.

Can anyone provide any help or ideas?

Thanks!